# Why data are not being inserted into database ,C# datagridview

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to do an insertion or update(based on if product exist on db)

```
       for (int i = 0; i < dtgartikulli.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    SqlCommand cmdkontrolla = new SqlCommand("barkodicheck", conn);
                    cmdkontrolla.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmdkontrolla.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barkodi", Convert.ToString(dtgartikulli.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
                    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdkontrolla);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapt.Fill(ds);
                    conn.Close();
                    int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                    //nese është barazi me 1, shfaqe dritaren pasuese
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmdinsertimi = new SqlCommand("insertprodukti", conn);
                        cmdinsertimi.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SqlParameter ibarkodi = cmdinsertimi.Parameters.Add("@barkodi", SqlDbType.Int);
                        SqlParameter iemertimi = cmdinsertimi.Parameters.Add("@emertimi", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
                        SqlParameter isasia = cmdinsertimi.Parameters.Add("@sasia", SqlDbType.Int);
                        SqlParameter istoku = cmdinsertimi.Parameters.Add("@stoku", SqlDbType.Int);
                        SqlParameter icmimi = cmdinsertimi.Parameters.Add("@cmimi", SqlDbType.Float);
                        SqlParameter icmimif = cmdinsertimi.Parameters.Add("@cmimif", SqlDbType.Float);
                        SqlParameter ifitimi = cmdinsertimi.Parameters.Add("@fitimi", SqlDbType.Float);
                        SqlParameter itvsh = cmdinsertimi.Parameters.Add("@tvsh", SqlDbType.Float);
                        SqlParameter ikategoria = cmdinsertimi.Parameters.Add("@kategoria", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                        SqlParameter idata = cmdinsertimi.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                        SqlParameter ishtuarnga = cmdinsertimi.Parameters.Add("@shtuarnga", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                        SqlParameter injesia = cmdinsertimi.Parameters.Add("@njesia", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgartikulli.Rows)
                        {
                            if (!row.IsNewRow)
                            {

                                ibarkodi.Value = row.Cells[0].Value;
                                iemertimi.Value = row.Cells[1].Value;
                                isasia.Value = "1";
                                istoku.Value = row.Cells[3].Value;
                                icmimi.Value = row.Cells[2].Value;
                                icmimif.Value = row.Cells[4].Value;
                                ifitimi.Value = row.Cells[5].Value;
                                itvsh.Value = row.Cells[7].Value;
                                ikategoria.Value = row.Cells[6].Value;
                                idata.Value = DateTime.Now;
                                ishtuarnga.Value = lbluseri.Text;
                                injesia.Value = row.Cells[9].Value;
                                cmdinsertimi.ExecuteNonQuery();


                            }
                        }


                    }
                    else if (count == 1)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dtgartikulli.Rows.Count; j++)
                        {

                            SqlCommand cmdeditimi = new SqlCommand("updatestokublerja", conn);
                            cmdeditimi.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmdeditimi.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barkodi", Convert.ToString(dtgartikulli.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value));
                            cmdeditimi.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sasi", Convert.ToString(dtgartikulli.Rows[j].Cells[3].Value));
                            conn.Open();
                            cmdeditimi.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            conn.Close();

                        }
                    }
                    clear();
                    conn.Close();
                    dtgartikulli.DataSource = null;
                    dtgartikulli.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

First i am checking if that barcode does exist(                    cmdkontrolla.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barkodi", Convert.ToString(dtgartikulli.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
)

SP CODE:

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[barkodicheck]
    @barkodi int

    as

    select Barkodi from tabela_produktet where
    Barkodi = @barkodi


    ALTER procedure [dbo].[updatestokublerja]
    @barkodi int,
    @sasi int

    as

    update tabela_produktet set Stoku = Stoku + @sasi
   where
   Barkodi = @barkodi
```

IN case if count ==0, data should be inserted
Else if count ==1 data should be update (where qty is provided)

The update of qty for data that exist is being executed fine( count==1 case), but new product isn't being inserted if data doesnt't exist( count==0 case)
What is wrong with code inside count ==1 block code

Thanks to everyone

Comment: How this SP looks like? updatestokublerja

Comment: added  required code in question

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the Stoku field on your table is not null? Because if it´s value = null all the value passed in your update will not change the field´s values.

```
update tabela_produktet set Stoku = Stoku + @sasi
   where
   Barkodi = @barkodi
```

Maybe you can change the command to:

update tabela_produktet set Stoku = ISNULL(Stoku,0) + @sasi
where
Barkodi = @barkodi

If your problem is in the Count == 0, I´ve tried this code with success.

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=xxxxx;Integrated Security=True;");
            try
            {
                var codebar = 12345;
                SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
                {
                new SqlParameter("@ProductId", codebar)
                };

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spu_GetCodeBar", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader != null && reader.Read()) 
                {
                    var code = reader["ProductID"];
                    MessageBox.Show($"I've found the record {code}!");
                    // do what you want to do
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Record not found!");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Null can't be, cause during the insert product process, the Stoku(qty) is mandatory, and the insert process can;t happen if the qty values is null(rollback).

Comment: The main problems is in insertion process (if count =0) not in update process (count =1)

Comment: could someone clarify me why these negative point, instead of downvoting , try helping someone

Comment: I tested the code provided in my question . If there are rows only in count==0 case the insertion process is done perfectly, but when there are multiple rows in both cases (count==0 and count==1 ) only the update process is done. I think the problem may be , into loop command where the prroduct is checked if it exist : barkodicheck command

Comment: Maybe your code has some logical mistake because if you have cases where count==0 and count==1 occurs, I believe that you can refactor the logic in another way.

Comment: @juinor , any example to reformat the logic code of the loop code

Comment: Hi, in the beginning of your code you´ve used:  for (int i = 0; i < dtgartikulli.Rows.Count; i++). This means that you´re scanning a Datagrid. Ok, but when you get the value of count, you start a new scan again in the command: foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgartikulli.Rows). I believe your problem is here, but I can understand some words you are using in your code because they´re probably written in your natural language.

Comment: Okay lets say that the problem may be as you said. What should i change in second loop when i begin to insert data from datagridview. First loop is to check if the product from dtg exist in sql , second loop to insert or update the data in sql( based on first loop if product exist or not)

Comment: I think you could remove the foreach of the count == 0. Because you´re processing all the rows in the first for command. If the row is found, it will insert, otherwise it will be updated!